# DataGridView.SelectedItem[0] to GenericType

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, anonymous-types

First I assign datacontext of DataGridView to an Anonymous Type which is obtained from Generic Class `Company` Anonymous type is preferred to get desired column names to be displayed in DataGridView.

```
    var companyData = (from c in dataContext.Companies 
           select new 
           {
               Company =c.CompanyName,
               City=c.City.CityName,

           });

    dataGridView.DataContext = companyData;
```

Now I want to get the select row values at time of MouseDoubleClick event. But the problem is I cannot convert the anonymous type back to my generic type Company.

```
void dataGridView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
           var selectedRow = dataGridView.SelectedItem[0];
           // How to convert selectedRow back to Company ? 
           // Anonymous type have no implementation of AsEnumerable.
}
```

I want something like this:

```
Company company = selectedRow.Select(c=>new Company
                                    (CompanyName=selectedRow.Company,
                                     CityName=selectedRow.City);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: But then I dont get desired column names for display purpose. I have mentioned my purpose of using anonymous type

Comment: I don't think there is any cleaner way to do this although there are some hacks. You should make a concrete class (for naming) and make list of class objects through LINQ query instead of anonymous type

Comment: Why do you need to convert the object back to a Company? Where is the original `Company` coming from?

Comment: @phoog: Its SQL Table and Linq-to-Sql Class

Comment: @Marshal the normal approach here would be to create a CompanyView type for display in the dataGridView control, rather than using an anonymous type.  That would make it easier to get the properties of the object out, and use them to get the correct company from your database.

Comment: @phoog Currently I just changed the Linq-To-Sql Class and Property Names to suit my display need. And its working fine now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Use Extension method to convert DataGridViewRow to Any Type

```
 public static class DataGridViewRowWExtenstions
    {
        public static T GetObject<T>(this DataGridViewRow Row) where T : new()
        {
            List<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();

            return CreateItemFromRow<T>(Row, properties);
        }

        private static T CreateItemFromRow<T>(DataGridViewRow row, List<PropertyInfo> properties) where T : new()
        {
            T item = new T();
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (row.DataGridView.Columns.Contains(property.Name))
                {
                    if (row.Cells[property.Name] != null)
                        property.SetValue(item, row.Cells[property.Name].Value, null);
                }
            }
            return item;
        }
    }



private void dataGridView2_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0];
            Company company = selectedRow.GetObject<Company>();
        }
```